# Java-Output all the columns and rows of a ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, database

`ta.setText` is a TextArea where I want to show all my data from the database, after a button click. But with `rs.get("name")` I just output one value and it is always the last. How can I print out the whole table from the database, so all the information which are stored there?

```
            try { String newquery = "SELECT * FROM kunden";
            java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(newquery);
            rs = ps.executeQuery(newquery);


            while (rs.next()){              

            ta.setText(rs.getString("name"));
            ta.setText(rs.getString("nachname"));
            }


        }// try
        catch(Exception e1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fail");


      }
      }//actionperformed
```

Comment: If you have multiple values, then you can't use `.setText` to display all of them, you would either need to display those values in a table component or concatenate all values before calling `.setText` on `ta`.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele thx for your answer. Yes there are two rows of data and I want to show them all. How can I handle that with component ?

Comment: You need to choose a component that displays multiple values... like a table, a list, etc. Seems like a table is your best option as you have also multiple columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you build a string an then set that string using setText()

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (rs.next()) {
   builder.append(rs.getString(“name”));
   builder.append(“ “);
   builder.append(rs.getString(“nachname”));
   builder.append(“\n“);       
}
ta.setText(builder.toString());
```

Or you use the append method that exists for TextArea

```
while (rs.next()) {
   ta.append(rs.getString(“name”));
   ta.append(“ “);
   ta.append(rs.getString(“nachname”));
   ta.append(“\n“);
}
```

Comment: thank you @Joakim Danielson. When I try that I get the error " The method getString(int) in the type ResultSet is no ablecable for th arguments ()."